# Is the word 'diplomat' a negative word?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

I've heard it many times. I searched the web and dictionary and found two meanings.

> An official engaged in international negotiations (this is clear to me).
>   
>   A person who deals tactfully with others (unclear).

We often say *Ah! Come on...stop being a diplomat.* Does it mean that we want the other person to be clear and straightforward (but then it's a bit negative) without playing with words? Does this word, by any means, refer to *cunningness?*

Comment: 1. It is *possible* to use any word negatively. That doesn't make it inherently negative. "Stop being a diplomat" means "Stop being tactful and say what you really mean" 2. "Often" is too strong-Google returns me just 24 hits, half of which are literal. 3. The noun is *cunning*, not *cunningness*.

Comment: It's only a "guesstimate", but Google thinks it's got about 625,000 results for [*"There's no need to **be diplomatic**"*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22there's+no+need+to+be+diplomatic%22&oq=%22there's+no+need+to+be+diplomatic%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.1945j0j1&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8) - which is certainly what I'm used to, rather than OP's version.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. *Being a diplomat* is always neutral in American or British English, and is normally used in the literal sense that someone works as a foreign emissary on official business.

In the figurative sense, we use "***being diplomatic***" rather than "being a diplomat". This is used to indicate that a person is being considerate of the views of others and deals with them tactfully (which is normally a compliment, and hence used positively).

> Mr Smith was very **diplomatic** during the meeting with union leaders.

Comment: I would add that for some groups "being political" has a similar meaning to being diplomatic, but with a more negative connotation, suggesting insincerity

Answer (score 1):

In US English, if you hear someone say, "Stop being a diplomat!", they are telling you to quit beating around the bush or putting a positive spin on something, and say what you mean in a straightforward way, even though it may be negative.

Being "diplomatic" or "a diplomat" doesn't really refer to "cunningness", but rather to putting things in a positive light, or not assigning blame, or  attempting to save face for all involved.